# Reading unknown length line

Tags: regex, string, matlab, parsing, text-processing

I have an unknown length line that is in this format

```
bobaboao dsaas : 5->2  2->3  4->6  7->2  1->4  5->1  8->1  222->1  23->13 ...
```

I need to read each

```
"X->Y"
```

and send to function

```
Dist(X,Y)
```

until the end of the line

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Have you actually tried something? fgets?

Comment: i did it in c,c++ but when i try sscanf and getreg for %f but its not working...

Comment: I'll write an answer.  One moment.

Comment: And have you tried fgets? Because it may work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `regexp` with `'tokens'`, which pulls out the bits of the match in between parentheses (`()`):

```
>> C = regexp(s,'(\d*)->(\d*)','tokens')
C = 
    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}   ...
    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}
>> xy = str2double(vertcat(C{:})).'
xy =
     5     2     4     7     1     5     8   222    23
     2     3     6     2     4     1     1     1    13
```

Then you have `X = xy(1,:);` and `Y = xy(2,:);`.

Explained: `\d` is a digit ([0-9]), `\d*` means any number of digits.  Wrapping them in `()` makes them tokens.  The whole pattern defines a match, but the tokens are extracted into a cell array of cell arrays, one cell array for each match, containing cell arrays for the tokens.  It's easy to make a single matrix with `vertcat` and convert it with `str2double`.

Comment: @rayryeng It's handy but it makes an ugly cell to dig through.

Comment: Though that may be the case, I find your code much more elegant... and I should probably use parenthesis groups more often.  BTW I forgot to give you a +1, so there you go!

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion I have is to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so that you search for substrings within that string in your example that specifically have one ID, followed by `->` followed by another ID.  Once we find these exact patterns in your string, we simply extract those out and place them into a cell array.  In other words, supposing that our string was stored in `s` (I'm actually going to use your example), do this:

```
s = 'bobaboao dsaas : 5->2  2->3  4->6  7->2  1->4  5->1  8->1  222->1  23->13';
g = regexp(s, '[0-9]+->[0-9]+', 'match');
```

Let's go through this code slowly.  `s` stores the string that you're analyzing, then the next line finds substrings in your string `s` that finds a sequence of at least one digit, followed by a `->`, followed by at least one digit.  The `'match'` flag extracts out the strings that match this pattern we are finding in `s`.  `g` is the output of this line, and each string is stored in a cell array.  We thus get:

```
g = 

  Columns 1 through 7

    '5->2'    '2->3'    '4->6'    '7->2'    '1->4'    '5->1'    '8->1'

  Columns 8 through 9

    '222->1'    '23->13'
```

Note that storing into a cell array is important, because the length of each substring may be different.

Once we extract these substrings, what we can do is extract the numbers **before** and **after** the `->`.  We simply apply two more regular expression calls to get the numbers before and after:

```
X = regexp(g, '^[0-9]+', 'match');
Y = regexp(g, '[0-9]+$', 'match');
```

The first call looks for substrings at the beginning of each string in `g` that starts with a number, while the second call looks for substrings at the end of each string in `g` that ends with a number.  What will be returned are the numbers contained in cell arrays.  Also, the numbers themselves are **strings**.  Because each element in the cell is a string, we should convert these back into actual numbers.  We should also place these into a numeric vector for you to use with your code:

```
X = cellfun(@str2double, X);
Y = cellfun(@str2double, Y);
```

[`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is a function that allows you to apply a particular function to each cell in a cell array.  In this case, we want to convert each number in the cell array as it's a string into `double`.  Therefore, use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to facilitate this conversion.  Once we're done, we will get numeric vectors that give you the numbers before the `->` and after the `->`.

We finally get:

```
X =

     5     2     4     7     1     5     8   222    23

Y =

     2     3     6     2     4     1     1     1    13
```

Comment: I love regex but can never get my head round them. Much appreciated when people explain what their regex do under the hood. Nice answer.

Comment: @Hoki - I recommend http://regexone.com - It was a website that Amro referred me to, and they have 20 very short simple tutorials that pertain to one aspect of regex that take about 2 minutes each.  Once you get through those, you'll be able to do some pretty advanced processing in no time.  Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for referring that website. Will definitely look at the 20 tutorials.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  @Hoki The `regexp` docs have a number of good examples, but learning it just takes a little... messing around.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a tricky way:

0)delete the alphabetical sequence by writing the following line:

```
  str(1:strfind(str,':'))=''
```

1)concatenate this string in the following way:

```
newStr=['[',str,']']
```

, so that now your new string will be: '[5->2  2->3  4->6  7->2  1->4  5->1  8->1  222->1  23->13]'

2)delete all the '>'  , you can do it by the command:

```
newStr(newStr=='>')=''
```

,so that now you will have '[5-2  2-3  4-6  7-2  1-4  5-1  8-1  222-1  23-13]',
pay attention that this is actually a string that represents a vector that contains the distances between the numbers, and that leads us to step 3...

3)evaluate the string we get:

```
distances=eval(newStr);
```

if you want the distances without + an - , just use abs() function.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how `newStr=['[',str,']']` would give `'[5->2 2->3 4->6 7->2 1->4 5->1 8->1 222->1 23->13]'`.  It seems that you may have forgotten the alphabetic sequence of characters before the number sequence.  How do you eliminate the alphabetic text at the beginning of the string before the sequence of numbers?  Also, using `eval` is considered bad practice.  I don't think it's necessary here.  Consider this article by Loren Shure from MathWorks: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/

Comment: 1) you're right, I didn't notice the alphabetical sequence was part of the string. so, we have to add step 0) which is to write the following line: str(1:strfind(str,':'))=''

Comment: 2) I think it is a legitimate way, however I think it's good you paste this link, so that every individual can take his own consideration about pros and cons that every method has and make the right choice for him.

Comment: (1) Cool.  I removed my downvote.  (2) I do agree that the use of `eval` is essentially a choice left for the programmer, and if it works for you, then I shouldn't stand in your way.  However, I try not to use it because the main thing with `eval` is that there is no optimization behind each command that is run through `eval`.  Either way, I'm nitpicking, but the point is that you described how to eliminate the leading alphabetic characters, and I have thus removed my downvote.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, and I absolutely agree with the cons you mentioned, but, as you said, it is the programmer's choice... (for example, if the string length is about 500 , you will probably agree that it doesn't realy matter if the computer do the calculation in 0.1 seconds instead of 0.01 seconds...)